# How to sort a list of datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am selecting 3 separate results from database by using select statement 3 times into a dataset.After that i am adding two rows and inserting a total label below second row and addition of result in next cell of that rows.I want to sort table in desc order based on table column values.My code is

```
 List<DataTable> list_dt = new List<DataTable>();

 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            score = TotalScore(ds.Tables[i]);
            list_dt.Add(AddToDataTable(ds.Tables[i], score));
        }
```

Problem is that how to sort tables based on hours so that i bind them to 3 different gridviews based on hours.

```
 public DataTable AddToDataTable(DataTable dt, double totalScore)
 {
    var rowTotal = dt.NewRow();
    rowTotal["FullName"] = "Total";
    rowTotal["Hours"] = totalScore;

    dt.Rows.Add(rowTotal);

    return dt;
}

public double TotalScore(DataTable dt)
{
    double Hours = 0.0;


    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Hours += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["Hours"]);
    }

    return Hours;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of this possible solutions to sort the tables in your list based on total hours.

```
var sortedTableList = (from table in list_dt
    orderby Convert.ToDouble((from row in table.AsEnumerable()
        where row.Field<string>("FullName") == "Total"
        select row.Field<string>("Hours"))
        .Single())
        /* place here the keyword "descending" for descending order */
    select table)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
// replace "OrderBy" with "OrderByDescending" for descending order
var sortedTableList = list_dt.OrderBy(table => 
    Convert.ToDouble(
        (table.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row => row.Field<string>("FullName") == "Total")
        .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Hours"))
        .Single())))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting the DataTables, You can use `Order By` in your query to sort your result by Hour descending.It's simple and easy because you are always sorting your resul according to Hour.

Comment: He says, 'I am selecting 3 separate results from database by using "select statement 3 times" into a dataset.' And the problem is 'Problem is that how to sort tables based on hours '

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. But the questions is "how to sort a list of datatables" (where one datatable is one resultset). And he also calculates the sum of hours for each resultset. And this calculated value should be used for sorting. Or not?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use Dictionary : [Click here for more info](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Way 2 : change your Sql Command and like this : select * from time order by Hours

other way is create 2 arraylist and then play with indexes of 2 arrays